# wrong xml in android apk

Tags: java, android, xml, apk

i am trying to build android app that calculate tip price.
this is how the xml look in android studio:
[image: eandroid studio]

and this is how the xml look actually in my phone, after i install the apk file:
[image]

i export an debug apk file, not release.
when i try to install the release apk file, i get error in my phone that Installation Certificate not found.
this is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gear.tip.MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="245dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="349dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="178dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="349dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you know the waiter?"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="284dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number of feasts:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="137dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="How was the service?\nFrom 1 to 100:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="192dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total price:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="65dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tip calculator"
        android:textColor="#d11723"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="245dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="200dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="197dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="129dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you stingy?"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="345dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="284dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="313dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="245dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="284dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="437dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

what can i do for fix it? (the both problems), thanks you guys.

Comment: i think your xml design is not working properly.you need to clean and rebuild your project. or please post your xml so we can looked into your design.

Comment: i now edit and add the xml code, thank.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to rush things with a release apk. Try to use the adb function to get the app directly on your device.

I tried to work with a release apk once and it did more harm than good. With the ADB you have much smoother testing foundation. Try it ... the app is on the phone even after disconnecting from the PC

Try to use LinearLayout with vertical orientation for your xml instead of constarint layout ... that should work wonders I think

and to keep the textView and EditText in line, use another linear layout in horizontal order

Comment: to go with your question: Is your code clean? e.g. it doesn't change anything on the layout? If you haven't done anything in code (except setting the view) and declared the activity in the manifest ... it should be looking like that in your editor

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have each relevant attribute listed as `tools:` which doesn't actually do anything other than show the result in the graphical editor in Android studio. Change it to `android:` and it should work.

Comment: i try change all to android without the toold: and with the tools and now when i try to build the apk file it give me a lot of errors... are you sure that all what i need to do is to change the tools: to android:?

Comment: Well, I don't know what other errors you're having, but to fix the layout problems all you need to do is change the `tools:`. Your best bet is to create another question for those.

Answer (score 0):

Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout

The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX.) These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.

Comment: tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="245dp"
 tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="349dp" this are not working in your code you have to implement once again or you can try with relative layout.